# How to understand the result of the spark sql window function

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code to try the spark sql window function:

```
test("spark sql time window 2") {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").appName("SparkSQLWindowTest").getOrCreate()
    import spark.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val ds = Seq(
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 09:01:12", 1),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 09:01:18", 6),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:11:12", 2),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:18:13", 5),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:22:13", 3),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:22:22", 6),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:34:56", 2),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 10:48:22", 6),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 11:52:23", 4),
      SaleRecord("2017-10-11 12:56:24", 2)).toDS

    val ds2 = ds.groupBy(window($"Time", "20 minutes", "9 minutes")).agg(sum("revenue")).orderBy("window.start")
    ds2.show(truncate = false)

    /*
+---------------------------------------------+------------+
|window                                       |sum(revenue)|
+---------------------------------------------+------------+
|[2017-10-11 08:45:00.0,2017-10-11 09:05:00.0]|7.0         |
|[2017-10-11 08:54:00.0,2017-10-11 09:14:00.0]|7.0         |
|[2017-10-11 09:57:00.0,2017-10-11 10:17:00.0]|2.0         |
|[2017-10-11 10:06:00.0,2017-10-11 10:26:00.0]|16.0        |
|[2017-10-11 10:15:00.0,2017-10-11 10:35:00.0]|16.0        |
|[2017-10-11 10:24:00.0,2017-10-11 10:44:00.0]|2.0         |
|[2017-10-11 10:33:00.0,2017-10-11 10:53:00.0]|8.0         |
|[2017-10-11 10:42:00.0,2017-10-11 11:02:00.0]|6.0         |
|[2017-10-11 11:36:00.0,2017-10-11 11:56:00.0]|4.0         |
|[2017-10-11 11:45:00.0,2017-10-11 12:05:00.0]|4.0         |
|[2017-10-11 12:39:00.0,2017-10-11 12:59:00.0]|2.0         |
|[2017-10-11 12:48:00.0,2017-10-11 13:08:00.0]|2.0         |
+---------------------------------------------+------------+


     */
  }
```

The definition of the SaleRecord is a simple case class:

```
case class SaleRecord(time: String, revenue: Double)
```

I could not understand how the first three rows is generated in the result?

Why the first window is 
`[2017-10-11 08:45:00.0,2017-10-11 09:05:00.0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window(timeColumn, windowDuration, slideDuration=None, startTime=None)
```

First, `window` function will create a time templet which mean:

```
zero = 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

[zero + startTime + slideDuration * n, zero + startTime + slideDuration * n + windowDuration)
```

For example:

```
window('ts', '5 seconds', '3 seconds', '2 seconds')
# is equal to :
['1970-01-01 00:00:02', '1970-01-01 00:00:07'),
['1970-01-01 00:00:05', '1970-01-01 00:00:10'),
['1970-01-01 00:00:08', '1970-01-01 00:00:13'),
['1970-01-01 00:00:11', '1970-01-01 00:00:16'),
...
```

Then, each row in your DataFrame will "fall into" time templet, according to **timeColumn**. 
One row can belong to many time templet cells.

Finally, drop all empty time templet cells and do `agg`.

Comment: Thanks @zhang-tong, excellent explanation, understand the `startTime` now

Answer (score 0):

With windows function, Spark will calcualte frames from unix epoch time `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`.
Because you set your the silde duration is `9 minutes`, so the first frame contains value from your `Time` column is `[2017-10-11 08:45:00.0,2017-10-11 09:05:00.0]`.

For clarity

```
$ date --date="2017-10-11 08:45:00" +"%s
1507686300
$ echo $[1507686300%180]
0
```

Comment: Thanks @cue...I didn't understand...the value `[2017-10-11 08:45:00.0,2017-10-11 09:05:00.0]` is the first row in the query result..

Comment: Because you have 2 records with `Time` value fall into that window.